# Getting Started with CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I've got CouchDB installed on my linux cloud server and I'm trying to access the "Futon Welcome Screen".  The O'Reilly book says to go to "127.0.0.1:portnum", but I'm not working on localhost, it is my remote server, so I should be able to use "xxx.xxx.xxx.x:portnum" (my remote address) to access Futon right?  This is not working, do I need a virtual host or something? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to your `local.ini` file. (probably in `/etc/couchdb`) and set `bind_address` to either `0.0.0.0` (ie. respond to all IP addresses) or specify another IP address that you're either using in your LAN (private) or over the internet. (public)

Comment: I'd suggest [turning off Admin Party](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/security.html), especially if one goes with the 0.0.0.0 bind address.

Comment: finally, restart the couchdb service to effect.