# How to configure Acralyzer?

Tags: android, ssh, acra

I've installed Acralyzer using [this tutorial](https://github.com/ACRA/acralyzer/wiki/setup#all-other-couchdb-versions)  and got following parameters for integrating Acra into my Android app:

```
httpMethod = Method.PUT,
reportType = Type.JSON,
formUri = "http://localhost:5984/acra-myap/_design/acra-storage/_update/report",
formUriBasicAuthLogin = "myap-reporter",
formUriBasicAuthPassword = "a11youneedisl0v3"
```

Before installing Acralyzer, I ran

```
ssh -L5984:127.0.0.1:5984 user@AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD
```

(establishes a tunnel to *CouchDB* running at `AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD`) where `AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD` is the address of my instance at *DigitalOcean*.

Smart as I am, after installing Acralyzer, I killed the ssh process and tried to open the URL `http://AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:5984/acra-myap/_design/acra-storage/_update/report`.

I could not connect to it from my browser, which means that the the Android app will not be able to send crash reports to Acralyzer.

What can I do in order for the Acralyzer's URL (`http://AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:5984/acra-myap/_design/acra-storage/_update/report`) to become available without ssh tunnel?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the port you are trying to contact is not open. You should inform `iptables` (the linux firewall), to *accept* the incoming traffic on port 5984:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5984 -j ACCEPT
```

You can find more information on how to create *iptables* rules and how to save them [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo).

Digital Ocean could have a firewall that will block you before reaching your server, but to open the port on your instance worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

By default the firewall on DigitalOcean machines is setup to accept all traffic, so the iptables rule shouldn't be necessary. The problem is more likely to be that the couchdb [bind_address is still set to the default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765028/getting-started-with-couchdb) "127.0.0.1" -- i.e. localhost. After defining an admin user account, you can set bind_address to "0.0.0.0" under configuration in the Futon control panel, which will make it listen to all ip addresses, or another specific address.